# Loop in excel column with Ruby horizontally. No one will help me?

Tags: ruby, capybara

Friends, the solution below solves my problem when there is a vertical column that validates the record in the cell with the field on the application screen. But if the spreadsheet is horizontally, I am not able to read the records and validate on the application screen.

**here OK I get the values ​​from the status column [invisible....etc]**

| fields | status |
| --- | --- |
| Leitura | Invisível |
| Hidrometro | Invisíve |
| Diametro | Invisível |
| Lacre | Obrigatório |

```
 Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'
book = Spreadsheet.open('c:/temp/gab.xls', "r")
sheet = book.worksheet 4
xls_offset = 1
row_offset = 2
sheet.each_with_index(xls_offset) do |row, idx|
 expected_tooltip = row[1]
 break if row[1].nil?
 expect(page).to have_css("tr.tvRow:nth-child(#{row_offset+idx}) .tvCell:nth-child(6) img[tooltip='#{expected_tooltip}']")
end
```

end

***How to adjust the code above to do this reading horizontally to read the records [Invisivel, Invisivel,Habilitado,Invisivel] in line 3 from the Leitura column?***

**Here NOK**

| code | situation | tab | leitura | hidrometro | diametro | lacre |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | ok | B | Invisivel | Invisivel | Habilitado | Invisivel |
| 9 | ok | C | Invisivel | Invisivel | Habilitado | Invisivel |
| 10 | ok | C | Invisivel | Invisivel | Habilitado | Invisivel |

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEK05.jpg)

Comment: Wait, so you're actually checking a web page, but data to check is in an excel file?

Comment: Sergio, how are you, Thanks for answering. This, the formula above runs without problems when the data is in a vertical position, but in a horizontal position I am not able to validate it. I use excel sheet data to validate against Browser data.

Comment: I puted a image to exemply better.